# youtube-dl : search keyword and only download urls

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

how can I use youtube-dl to only download the urls after a search for keywords.
e.g. `youtube-dl "gvsearch1:how to create android app in app studio"` downloads the entire video , I only need the urls for a keyword(s) search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out

`youtube-dl gvsearch5:how to develop for android --no-playlist --write-info-json --write-annotation --write-thumbnail --write-sub --skip-download"`

The 5 in `gvsearch5` is the n, for 10 results make it `gvsearch10`.
The output files are json and xml files for each result and those contain the youtube url.

Hope this is of help to someone.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone stumbled on this answer like I did and wants to do the same for ytsearch you could do `youtube-dl "ytsearch:how to develop for android" --get-id` and then just generate a youtube link from that id with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDGOESHERE